# Determining if a time stamp is an exact hour

Tags: java, time, utc

I need to determine if a time stamp is an exact hour (i.e. it represents a time with no minutes, seconds or milliseconds components) - using primitives only.  The code is called several hundred times per second and I don't want the overhead of a `Calendar` or other object.

I've tried this but rounding errors cause the comparison to fail.

```
 float hours = (time / 3600000f);
 boolean isExactHour = hours == (int)hours;
```

For example, if time = 1373763600470, hours = 381601.03125.  That time stamp represents 01:00:00:000 GMT today and hours should be 381601.

Any ideas for a quick and simple way to do this?  Thanks!

[EDIT]

It seems that this is more complex than at first sight (when is it not? :)

For clarity, I don't care about time zones, nor leap seconds.  The time stamp is generated by a method which returns the previous midnight - i.e. 13 July 2013 00:00:00:000 for today.  I am then calculating, for any time stamp in an array of longs which is always this initial time stamp plus/minus an exact multiple of 5 minutes.  My aim to to determine if a given stamp is "top of the hour".  I might have edge cases where the multiple of 5 minutes overlaps a year end but I can live with those.

Comment: *"Any ideas for a quick and simple way to do this?"*  Ask strangers on the internet to 'do it for you'?  Oh, you already have that covered..

Comment: Are you sure, that `1373763600470` represents 01:00:00:000 and not 01:00:00:470 ?

Comment: Erm, why would you attempt to use `float` for anything that is *exact* ? I think you're looking for a [modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

Comment: @Algorithmist Why exactly do you think you need more examples?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I put far more into SO than I take out.  I didn't ask anyone to do anything, simply asked for ideas and occasionally, like all humans, I get things wrong.  Especially at the end of really long sessions.

Comment: @Simon: In which timezone do you want the exact hour? Timestamps are based on UTC, not on localtime.

Comment: @A.H.I don't need to care about time zones.  Simply whether any give time is "top of the hour".  The exact usage scenario is a data graph where time is the X axis.  The x series datapoints are all timestamps (actually, starting at an exact hour and incrementing every 5 minutes.  The calculation is to determine the x series labels which show whole hours only.

Comment: There are timezones that are offset from UTC by amounts that are not a whole number of hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(time % 36000000) == 0
```

Surely this is obvious?

**EDIT**

To get accuracy w.r.t. leap seconds, assuming a lookup table of leap seconds indexed by year since (say) 1970, something like:

```
((time-leapSeconds[(int)(time/(1000*60*60*24*365.2425))-1970]*1000) % 3600000) == 0
```

Programmers needing this level of accuracy should also see all of Einar's comments below.

Comment: Doh, doh, doh, doh, doh.  Thanks!  Too much time between the keyboard and the chair.

Comment: What about leap-seconds? I'd use a Calendar and check millis, seconds and minutes fields are 0.

Comment: I dont think this gives you the correct answer. The concept of leap seconds is not taken into account. They are about +1 second/ year and since the timestamp is the number of seconds since 00:00:00 1/1 1970 you will probably be off about 30-40 seconds.

Comment: @jackrabbit The OP specifically stated (1) 'primitives only' (2) very high performance and (3) 'no Calendar objects'.

Comment: To get this with high performance you must keep track of the present and upcoming leap seconds. ((time - currentlyPassedLeapSeconds) % 36000000 =0) would be a step towards what you are after.

Comment: @Einar Well, you need to know how many leap seconds apply to the given value. There's no 'present' or 'upcoming' or 'current' or 'passed' about it, unless the time values are just monotonically increasing clock ticks, which isn't stated.

Comment: @EJP Of course you are right. I was just assuming you made such a method. To do that the method needs to keep track of how many leap second has passed at any given point in time and return that number. But this needs to be done using a table of leap seconds since they are occuring slightly randomly.

Comment: @EJP You might want to add this to your answer: To keep the table  up to date you also need to keep track of upcoming leap seconds by consulting [Bureau International de l'Heure (BIH)][1] at least two times/year since they announce leap seconds six months in advance.
  [1]: ftp://hpiers.obspm.fr/iers/bul/bulc/bulletinc.dat

Comment: @EJP too early for me, that part of the question escaped me somehow. Still, if the OP wants accuracy, he has to take them into account. Einar covered it well already.